# Logarithm in Private Set Intersection

Tags: private-set-intersection

Is the logarithm in the private set intersection protocol mentioned in Section 3.4, Step 5 of http://www.ece.umd.edu/~danadach/MyPapers/set-int.pdf, a base 10 or 2? How do we find this out?

Answer (score 2):

It is of base $2$ since it is the number of bits needed to represent in binary form $n$.